# Matrix loop (nesting?) issue using switch

Tags: templating, craft3, matrix, bootstrap-craft

First let me say this: I'm new to Craft and Twig. So: my apologies for probably overlooking the obvious. I hope you can offer me some help... I've been trying for a couple of days to solve this puzzle. Nothing seems to work. ;-S

I'm trying to create a simple events calendar using Craft 3, Twig and Bootstrap 4. The calendar exist of two parts: 1. a section with 3 columns (col-4) that lists the events; and 2. a divider (col-12) that contains the month and year. I used the Matrix field in Craft to be able to be flexible in sorting events within a certain period of time.

The Issue:
I expected to see the three columns to neatly sit beside each other horizontally (on the desktop version of the site). But this doesn't seem to work right now: because I use a for loop to enable switch, the for loop I need for outputting the event-items results in the same row of events being repeated a couple of times instead of just once.

What am I doing wrong?

I very much appreciate any thoughts.

Greetings from The Netherlands, sorry for my bad English,

Mars

```
{% block calendar %}

    {% for block in entry.calendarGroup.all() %}

        {% switch block.type %}

            {% case "events" %}

                <div class="row no-gutters">

                    {% for entries in entry.calendarGroup.type('events') %}

                        <div class="col-md-4 pt-1 pb-1 pb-md-0 pr-md-1">
                            <div class="box-calendar black text-white">
                                <div class="row no-gutters p-3">
                                    <div class="col-2 pl-lg-1 pt-1">
                                        <h5>{{ block.eventDate }}</h5>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-10 pt-1 pr-2">
                                        <h5>{{ block.eventTitle }}</h5>
                                        <ul class="pt-1 mt-1 calendar-brood">
                                            <li class="uppercase">{{ block.eventType }}</li>
                                        </ul>

                                        <ul class="pt-3 mt-1 calendar-brood">
                                            <li>{{ block.eventTime }}</li>
                                            <li>{{ block.eventLocation }}</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="pt-3 mt-1 pb-3 calendar-brood">{{ block.eventDescription }}</div>
                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                            </div> 
                        </div>

                    {% endfor %}

                </div>

            {% case "months" %}

                <div class="row no-gutters">

                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="calendar-bar d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-md-center">
                            <p class="d-flex align-self-center agenda-item left w-25">{{ block.month }}</p>
                            <p class="d-flex align-self-center agenda-item right">{{ block.year }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> <!-- End row -->

            {% endswitch %}
        {% endfor %}

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Jeremy, for helping out! I really appreciate it. I solved the issue today using the "Super Table"-plugin (matrix within a matrix).

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block calendar %}

{% for row in entry.eventCalendar.all() %}

<div class="row no-gutters">

{% for block in row.months.all() %}

  <div class="col-12">
   <div class="calendar-bar d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-md-center">
      <p class="d-flex align-self-center agenda-item left w-25">{{ block.month }}</p>
      <p class="d-flex align-self-center agenda-item right">{{ block.year }}</p>
   </div>
  </div>

{% endfor %}

</div> <!-- End row -->

<div class="row no-gutters">

{% for block in row.eventInfo.all() %}

     <div class="col-md-4 pt-1 pb-1 pb-md-0 pr-md-1">
      <div class="box-calendar black text-white">
        <div class="row no-gutters p-3">

          <div class="col-2 pl-lg-1 pt-1">
            <h5>{{ block.eventDate }}</h5>
          </div>

          <div class="col-10 pt-1 pr-2">
            <h5>{{ block.eventTitle }}</h5>
            <ul class="pt-1 mt-1 calendar-brood">
              <li class="uppercase">{{ block.eventType }}</li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="pt-3 mt-1 calendar-brood">
              <li>{{ block.eventTime }}</li>
              <li>{{ block.eventLocation }}</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pt-3 mt-1 pb-3 calendar-brood">{{ block.eventDescription }}</div>
          </div>

      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
{% endfor %}

</div> <!-- End row -->

{% endfor %}

</div> <!-- End Calendar -->

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This question seems to be related more to your frontend framework not Craft.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear what your Matrix blocks/fields are setup like, so it's a little hard to tell what's going on here.

But I'm going to take a stab at it.

Your outer loop is looping through all the blocks in the `calendarGroup` Matrix field.

Then you're using a switch to determine which piece of code to execute based on which one of the two block types each block is.

All that looks ok.

But here is *I think* where your problem lies:

```
{% for entries in entry.calendarGroup.type('events') %}


{% endfor %}
```

This loop is starting fresh and looping over all the Matrix blocks in the `calendarGroup` Matrix field, except this time it's *only* getting the blocks of the *event* block type.

Then, inside that loop you are using the `{{ block.fieldName }}` variables again. But `block` is set in your parent loop. And nowhere are you referencing `entries` from your inner loop.

So there is a mismatch in your logic. I think you can simply do away with the inner loop, it's it's going to out put all of the `event` blocks inside each `event` block in the outer loop.  That, to me, seems like the issue.